# What is an SSL debug file

Tags: wireshark, sslvpn, pcap

What is an SSL debug file in wireshark? I am following the below tutorial and I am stuck at step 4 of [this set of Citrix Netscaler instructions](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX116557)